# What does mean that MongoDB's BSON be traversable?

Tags: mongodb, bson

According to the BSON's description given by the MongoDB website, they claim that BSON implementation is [highly ***traversable***](https://www.mongodb.com/json-and-bson)

**The problem**

What does "traversable" mean in this context?

I need to know this for translation purposes, because translating "traversable" in a literally way looks "odd" in spanish. Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards.

Comment: It means something like `altamente navegable` or `fácil de recorrer`...you can have a lot of nested objects or nested arrays, or nested object arrays inside a `bson` document, but, just like `json` `es fácil de recorrer`.

Comment: So I can iterate over  a BSON,object, because it's clear and straightforward? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Exactamente compatriota!!!!

Comment: jajaja compatriota!!! muchas gracias!!!